# Why are the font-awesome icons not showing?

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I've created an angular project and for beauty reasons i want to use font-awesome icons.
I installed it like this:

```js
npm install font-awesome
```

And then added it to javascript in my angular.json:

```js
"styles": [
  "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
]
```

Already checked, the path is correct (for my setup)

So when i now try to add the "plus" icon for example (which is included in the free version) it just shows like a weird placeholder...

I added the icon like this:

```html
<i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
```

Hope you guys can help me

Comment: I couldn't get FA font to render consistently in `angular` until i switched to the `fa-icon` component as described here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome

Comment: Try `<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>`

Comment: @AndrewAllen Thank you so much, that actually works. For some reason though the actual font-awesome website says it should be "fas fa-plus-circle"

Comment: @niehoelzz yeah, I only discovered this through trial and error. I'll be interested if anyone can explain why fas version does not show.

Comment: I thinks its a version thing. fa fa-plus-circle refers to font awesome 3. fas fa-plus-circle is font awesome 4. You could also consider removing font-awesome from "styles": in angular.json and @import it in you own stylesheet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the question has been answered already in the comments, here is a short summary:

Font Awesome has several versions, the newest one is **5.15.1** ([relying on the GitHub repository](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/releases)). However, [in the NPM repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome) the authors have still published the older version **4.7.0**.

The name of the base class for Font Awesome has changed from `fa` in version 4.x to `fas` in version 5.x. And because the documentation refers to the newest version, but the NPM package version is older, you must change `fas` to `fa` everywhere.

**Edit:** As I discovered, in Font Awesome 5.x there are also several classes of alternative icon styles, like `far` or `fab`. In case of doubt, you should check to which style class each individual icon belongs.

Nevertheless, the newest version of Font Awesome has been published as well at NPM under the package name [`@fortawesome/fontawesome-free`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free).

Answer (score 0):

Change `fas` to `fa`

if you have the code like this `<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>`
change to this `<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>`

That is occurring because of a version issue.