# How to update font-awesome sass from 4.7 to 5.12.1

Tags: font-awesome-5, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using font-awesome 4.7 sass in asp net core project and want to update to version 5.12.1.
unpgk in VS 2019 offers only 4.7

Answer (score 0):

FontAwesome 5 has been released under a new official package name: [@fortawesome/fontawesome-free](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/v/5.1.0-9)

You just have to change the package name declaration and refactor all your existing classes from `fa` to `fas`.

See also [this answer post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57804961/2764486).